# Can Killmonger's gold Black Panther suit absorb kinetic energy?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-man, black-panther-2018

In the MCU, can Killmonger's gold Black Panther suit absorb kinetic energy from Iron Man's missiles and repulsor blasts?

In general can Killmonger's gold suit absorb regular kinetic energy, like T'Challa's can?

Answer (score 5):

Killmonger's gold suit is the exact same as T'Challa's silver one. They are both presented to T'Challa by Shuri during the movie, but T'Challa says the gold one is "Tempting, but the idea is not to be noticed." Here is that clip from the movie.

And seeing how T'Challa's suit is able to absorb a large variety of kinetic attacks, then Killmonger's would be able to do the same.

Comment: So @virusbomb, would Erik die from a missile strike from Tony Stark or simply get overloaded?                 Also what would happen to black panthers suit from tony starks EMP in the MCU?

Comment: The thing about *Black Panther* was that the theaters had to show that Wakanda had advanced vibranium technology while at the same time maintaining the core Avengers as the awesomeness. So from a strict worldbuilding perspective, T'Challa's suit should be better than Iron Man's (technological headstart plus better materials plus similar scientific brilliance). But based on what's shown in film, it's on the same level or a little less capable. I think he'd take a hit but it would hurt.

Comment: And the cardinal rule, as shown in Captain America Civil War. If it's a Black Panther movie, T'Challa's wins. If it's an Iron Man movie, Tony wins.

Comment: @Adamant Thanks for your response, I really appreciate! :)

Comment: Sooooo, this seems _likely_, but it's possible the gold one has a different set of optimizations for different use. The scene doesn't really speak to that.